# Class not found Onumoti in Controller

Tags: laravel, request, package

I am facing an error Class "App\Http\Controllers\Onumoti" not found When i install package composer require laramin/utility, REQUEST_SCHEME error come, when i remove this package it show me that error "App\Http\Controllers\Onumoti", How can i solve it, I am new in Laravel using laravel version 9.2

This is only happening when i login to admin dashboard i pass out the credentials and then error comes, behind this a constructor is defined:

```
 public function __construct() 
{ 
    $this->activeTemplate = activeTemplate();
    $className = get_called_class();
    Onumoti::mySite($this,$className);
}
```

in this constructor "Onumoti" class is used which package is removed.

Comment: Please provide link to the repo/lib you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said, the problem came from the missing class `Onumoti` . You need to import the class first

You can import it by putting:

```
use Laramin\Utility\Onumoti;
```

and it should be fixed. Reference class from [laramin/utility](https://github.com/kbzaman76/utility/blob/main/src/Onumoti.php)

Comment: If i add this class it gave me the error of undefined array key "REQUEST_SCHEME"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `Onumoti::mySite($this,$className);`

And the import statement `use Laramin\Utility\Onumoti;`

You also need to look at the other files which import from `laramin`.

I believe this is a viserlabs.com version of `laramin`, for backdooring the products they sell.
They are an unethical bunch, I'd definitely remove all this stuff.

Look in laramin/utility/src/VugiChugi.php. You'll see the cleverly encrypted strings like `uggcf://yvprafr.ivfreyno.pbz/hcqngrf/irefvba`.

Actually they're just [str_rot13](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_rot13.asp) obfuscated.

Undone, they are:

```
activate
activate_system_submit
checkProject
tbgbpber (gotocore)
home
Activate
https://license.viserlab.com/updates/version/
https://license.viserlab.com/activate
Laramin\Utility\Controller\UtilityController
prependMiddleware
pushMiddlewareToGroup
loadRoutesFrom
https://viserlab.com/support
```

Normally I wouldn't disclose this stuff on a site like stackoverflow, but this company straight up robbed me. Took my money, didn't provide a service, wouldn't refund to my bank, and then locked me out of my account after complaining too much.

Don't just take my word for it, https://www.trustpilot.com/review/viserlab.com.

Given this information, I hope you can make an informed decision about the error you have.